# Steam can't find my account, offline data deleted, now what?

Tags: steam

Steam for Mac refuses to log me in and it thinks my account does not exist. What can I do to fix this? I was in offline mode for a while, but now I'm getting errors when trying to log in or recover my account.

**Edit:**

I reinstalled, nothing doing. I contacted steam. Now I suppose I wait. While waiting, I am wondering if playing "The Heist" could have trashed my account. At the end, they ask you to create a Steam account. It seems like that might have overwritten or trashed my old account. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Sounds major enough to contact Steam support.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Okay, I'm reinstalling Steam now, then I'm going to try to contact them. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I had a similar problem on Windows a while ago but it went away quickly and I don't know what I did. Hope you solve it.

Comment: @MatthewRead Reinstalling now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to [log in at steampowered.com](http://store.steampowered.com/login/) so you can see whether it's a client or login data issue. Also make sure you don't use your community profile name instead of the username (they can be different, it took me a while to remember that after not having used steam for a while).

If you also cannot login there, follow [theses instructions from steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4988-DHXV-7272), basically it means installing the client again (as you intended to do anyway) and selecting `I don't know my account name` (it will be emailed to your registered address) or `I know my account name` if you are certain about it (asking for the answer of the secret question).

If this still fails, [contact support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1223-QROC-4460).

Comment: Failed, seamy edits.

Comment: @Moshe what happened after choosing `I (don't) know my account name`? Any emails, maybe accidentally caught by your spam filter?

Comment: I dont believe that the spam filter caught anything. The client claims it failed to send the email.

Comment: @Moshe Did you maybe use a different email address? **edit this out:** The worst case scenario would of course be someone hijacked your steam _and_ email account (I hope you use a different password!) and deleted the support requests.

Comment: @Moshe I don't know if one can change the email address at steam, but basically that *could* have happened. If all else fails, look at steams [help my account was hijacked](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?s=9149f2fe0b6ed04eb3233eef4950507b&ref=2347-QDFN-4366) support site

Comment: Steam reset the password. I needed to log in on the website and authorize my computer. Then, the client worked.